# ids of comments have changed

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are requesting comments from YouTube API. Up until earlier today everything worked as expected.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list

But since a few hours ago it seems like all ids of comments have changed. If we request the same data, new ids for the same comments are returned.

Example of the returned value yesterday:

```json
{
        "snippet" : {
            "updatedAt" : "2017-12-02T15:25:18.000Z",
            "publishedAt" : "2017-12-02T15:25:18.000Z",
            "likeCount" : 0,
            "viewerRating" : "none",
            "canRate" : true,
            "textOriginal" : "Wer cool wenn ihr das auch bei der    linie 9 nach königsforst  machen könnt",
            "textDisplay" : "Wer cool wenn ihr das auch bei der    linie 9 nach königsforst  machen könnt",
            "videoId" : "HM9HTudhtI8",
            "authorChannelId" : {
                "value" : "UC65X_3QoSnkPiKSnuCX1Eqg"
            },
            "authorChannelUrl" : "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC65X_3QoSnkPiKSnuCX1Eqg",
            "authorProfileImageUrl" : "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-pC2fJDx46os/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/koDhQIPnvF0/s28-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg",
            "authorDisplayName" : "Dani stayler 04"
        },
        "id" : "z22ocjgrmmvvujbloacdp43bypow13uddt5ygnzglfxw03c010c",
        "etag" : "\"7991kDR-QPaa9r0pePmDjBEa2h8/LT00v-6zSoJQnYNF--QlclbxuFM\"",
        "kind" : "youtube#comment"
    }
```

example of the same comment now:

```json
{
        "snippet" : {
            "updatedAt" : "2017-12-02T15:25:18.000Z",
            "publishedAt" : "2017-12-02T15:25:18.000Z",
            "likeCount" : 0,
            "viewerRating" : "none",
            "canRate" : true,
            "textOriginal" : "Wer cool wenn ihr das auch bei der    linie 9 nach königsforst  machen könnt",
            "textDisplay" : "Wer cool wenn ihr das auch bei der    linie 9 nach königsforst  machen könnt",
            "videoId" : "HM9HTudhtI8",
            "authorChannelId" : {
                "value" : "UC65X_3QoSnkPiKSnuCX1Eqg"
            },
            "authorChannelUrl" : "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC65X_3QoSnkPiKSnuCX1Eqg",
            "authorProfileImageUrl" : "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-pC2fJDx46os/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/koDhQIPnvF0/s28-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg",
            "authorDisplayName" : "Dani stayler 04"
        },
        "id" : "Ugz-rTgR6SnJfMn9kV94AaABAg",
        "etag" : "\"7991kDR-QPaa9r0pePmDjBEa2h8/OgzbWigUN6XJyrzDu4RuZWYN-0k\"",
        "kind" : "youtube#comment"
    }
```

Does anybody else have this problem? Is this by design? Did YouTube change something and we missed an announcement?

Comment: Same for us! Did not find an official bug report or a changelog entry yet!

Comment: we are experiencing this problem as well. I created a bug-report in googles issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/70258423 I couldn't find an announcement for that change, so all i can do for now is confirming the problem.

Comment: A collague of mine created an issue in the official bug tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/70258423 feel free to star the issue!